# How to avoid boilerplate code in my models?

Tags: php, codeigniter, orm, model

I am using CI, however this question applies to models and db persistence in general. I find myself creating methods in models like:-

```
private function create_joins() {
  # Add some joins to the global db object using the active record 
}
```

I do this so I can then perform common joins for a particular model without duplicating the code for creating the joins.

So a select method might be:-

```
public function get_by_id($id) {

    $this->db->select('some_cols');
    $this->db->from('some_table');
    $this->create_joins();
    $this->db->where(array('id' => $id));
    etc...
}
```

Which is fine, but I am wondering if this is the sort of thing that an ORM like datamapper can abstract away?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should try [Doctrine](http://www.doctrine-project.org/), which is one of the most advanced ORM in PHP:

Using Doctrine, you won't even have to write methods such as `get_by_id($id)` in your model : they are handled by Doctrine itself.
So you would be able to write:

```
$entityManager->find("Bug", $id);
```

Comment: [Integrating Doctrine with CodeIgniter](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/cookbook/integrating-with-codeigniter.html)

Comment: A valuable alternative is [Datamapper ORM](http://datamapper.wanwizard.eu/), an ORM specifically for codeigniter.

Comment: Thanks, I'm going to look into both of these

Answer (score 0):

An alternative is to use [php-activerecord](http://www.phpactiverecord.org/) via [sparks](http://getsparks.org/packages/php-activerecord/versions/HEAD/show)

**An example of Associations**
    -

```
class User extends ActiveRecord\Model{

    //set tablename 
    //I would advice to keep Model singular and table names plural
    //then this next step is not needed
    static $table_name = 'table_one';

    //set relationships
    static $belongs_to array(
        array('Group')
    );

    static $has_many = array(
       array('Comment'),
       array('Order')
    );

    static $has_one = array(
       array('Additional_Info')
    );

    //one key feature is callbacks
    //this helps keep controllers clean by letting you pass
    //the post data(after validation) in to modify(serialize,json_encode,calculate vat etc) 

    static $before_create = array('json_encode_my_tags');

    public function json_encode_my_tags(){
        //$this->tags === $this->input->post('tags');
        $tags = explode(',', str_replace(' ', '', $this->tags));
        return $this->tags = json_encode($tags, TRUE);
    }
}

//calling a model and using eager-loading for associations
$model = User::find(array(
    'conditions'    =>    array('id=?', $id) // PK Primary key
    'include'       =>   array('comment', 'order', 'additional_info') // eager-loading associations
)); 

$model->key;
$model->comment->key;
$model->additional_info->key;
$model->order->key;
```